# Proving a property about alpha cut $ (A')_\alpha \neq (A_\alpha)', unless \\ \alpha = 0.5 $

Tags: inequality, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-set

I recently came accross this property about alpha (or lambda) cuts

$$
(A')_\alpha \neq (A_\alpha)', unless \\ \alpha  = 0.5
$$
where A is a fuzzy set with membership function $\mu_A(x)$

I am curious about the equality condition which I tried proving it as follows:-

We know that

$$
\mu^{'}_{A}(x) = 1 - \mu_A(x)
$$

Now

$$
A_\alpha = \{x | \mu_A(x)\geq \alpha \}
$$

$$
\implies (A_\alpha)' = \{ x | \mu_A(x) < \alpha \}
$$

Similarly

$$
(A')_\alpha = \{ x | 1 - \mu_A(x) \geq \alpha \}
$$

Given that

$$
(A')_\alpha = (A_\alpha)'
$$

We thus have

$$
\{ x | 1 - \mu_A(x) \geq \alpha \} = \{ x | \mu_A(x) < \alpha \}
$$

$$
\implies 1 - \mu_A(x) \geq \alpha 
$$

And

$$
\mu_A(x) < \alpha
$$

$$
\implies 1 - 2\alpha \geq 0
$$

$$
\implies \alpha \leq 0.5
$$

This is where I am stuck, how do I go about eliminating the inequality and obtain just $\alpha = 0.5$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume that $'$ indicates complementation? In particular, fuzzy set complementation on the LHS and regular set complementation on the right? If so, and if I haven't completely forgotten something about the definition of fuzzy sets, this is false. Let $U = \{a, b\}$ be the universe of discourse, and $\mu_A(a) = 0.1, \mu_A(b) = 0.9$. If $\alpha = \frac 13$, then $A_\alpha = \{b\}, (A_\alpha)' = \{a\}, (A')_\alpha = \{a\}$,